# Replacing ascii or unicode in a string with its literal value

Tags: java, arrays, regex, ascii, libraries

I am parsing through a string in Java that can contain values like

```
{
&#34 key1&#34 :2016842408,
&#34 key2&#34 :1462658047,
&#34 key3&#34 :2809333377,
&#34 key4&#34 :1262339872,
&#34 key5&#34 :&#34 0x4B3DC720&#34 ,
&#34 key6&#34 :true
}
```

If you look close at this example, its really just a JSON with some of the keys/values wrapped in quotes (quotes are ASCII value 34).

Does there exist a library or API which can regex through a string, find `&#(\\d+)` and replace it with the ASCII character corresponding to `\\d+`?

I know I could probably write this out, use `.group(1)` to extract the ASCII code and replace it within the corresponding character, but I got to think there is already a robust library out there that has taken security into account, etc?

Comment: Seems like input was incorrectly encoded in the first place. Can you ask input provider to fix the bug?

Comment: could you tell us what code or API produces this output ?

Comment: If there are actually semicolons after the numbers, as in `&#34;` instead of `&#34 ` then it could be an HTML or XML fragment, containing JSON. If so, please [edit] your question.